# Redirect HTTP TO HTTPS for custom HTTPS port for Omnisus Gitlab with Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, http-redirect, gitlab-omnibus

I have the newest Omnibus GitLab Docker image, and the `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'some_ip'
  container_name: 'some_name'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://some_ip'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 4381
      nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
      nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
  ports:
    - '6312:443'
    - '4381:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

When accessing https://some_ip:6312 it works fine, but for some_ip:6312 it displays:

> 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port nginx

The reason is obvious, but how to get around this? Must I set `ssl off` for nginx, if so, how do I do that for the Docker image?

I've tried different combinations of adding the following lines, but no success:

```
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
gitlab_rails['gitlab_https'] = false
gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 443
nginx['ssl'] = 'off'
nginx['listen_port'] = 443
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

EDIT:
In short: I want the user, who connects to the website via `some_ip:6312` or `http://some_ip:6312`, to be **redirected** to `https://some_ip:6312`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to run `http` and `https` on the same port

https://askubuntu.com/questions/860511/is-it-possible-to-set-same-port-work-with-http-and-https

When you use `https://domain/` the port is automatically assumed as `443` and in case of `http://domain/` it is assumed as `80`. So both of them actually run on different port.

Comment: I know, I've stated that it's obvious that HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port, which won't work. See my edit.

Comment: Let me check but I still doubt that a redirect can be done on custom port. You need to put another nginx in front and use normal ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Why does the custom port present a problem? Is this nginx specific?